# Vulkan: Support alpha channel for sprites

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to draw some sprites where the alpha channel of the image is taken into account.

What is the correct set of values for the following structures to support alpha channel of textures in the fragment shader?

```
vk::PipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment; 
colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eR | vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eG | vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eB | vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eA;
colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable    = VK_TRUE;
colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eOne;
colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eZero;
colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp        = vk::BlendOp::eAdd;   
colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eOne;
colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eZero;  
colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp        = vk::BlendOp::eSubtract;


vk::PipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending;    
colorBlending.logicOpEnable     = VK_FALSE;
colorBlending.logicOp           = vk::LogicOp::eCopy;
colorBlending.attachmentCount   = 1;
colorBlending.pAttachments      = &colorBlendAttachment;
colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;
```

Comment: Here is [Alpha Blending example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Samples/Source%20Files/Other/13-Enabling_Alpha_Blending/main.cpp) from the Vulkan Cookbook. But various blending settings give various results depending on Your needs. Just try different combinations, we don't know what exactly do You want to achieve. But if You want to "cut" sprites from quads (without blending) You may want to give a fragment shader's discard instruction a try (earlier it was called alpha test, but now it can only be done inside a fragment shader).

Comment: @Ekzuzy: You posted the answer as a comment, so there's no button to accept. But, consider it accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Per Ekzusy's answer, here are 2 ways:

Using the 'discard' keyword in the fragment shader.

```
// Read data from some texture.
vec4 color = texture(...); 
// This makes the alpha channel (w component) act as a boolean.    
if (color.w < 1) { discard; }
```

For my original question, these values will do:

```
vk::PipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment;
colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = 
  vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eR | vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eG |
  vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eB | vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eA;
colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eSrcAlpha;
colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eOneMinusSrcAlpha;
colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = vk::BlendOp::eAdd;
colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eSrcAlpha;
colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = vk::BlendFactor::eOneMinusSrcAlpha;
colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = vk::BlendOp::eSubtract;
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what You were expecting. There are plenty of different alpha blending settings for various situations. So I just pointed You to the most commonly used one so You could start from there. But I'm glad this helped You in Your development. ;-)

Comment: Note: I hadn't noticed before, but these values for the blend replaces the pixels that are not written with the clear color. So, when the sprite is not over another sprite, the sprite seems transparent. But, when the sprite is drawn over another sprite, the part that would be transparent is shown in the clear color. I'll post a note when I figure out what's happening there.

Comment: Probably due to depth test being enabled. If You draw a quad, it is blending with a clear color. Now when You draw another quad, but one that is behind the first quad, it fails the depth test and is not drawn at all (or only in places when it is not covered). If You want the blending to be correct, You have to sort objects by their distance. In case of transparent objects, game engines sort them and draws objects that are further away first, then those that are closer to the camera. This happens after all opaque geometry is drawn.

Comment: Damn. And I thought it would be easy.